# Changing Date on large numbers of scanned files

Tags: exiftool

I have thousands of scanned photos and would like to change the EXIF data to have the proper dates.
I can do this all with exiftool, but am looking for a way to process the files after I have organized the files into groups by date.

I created subfolders with the format *mmddyy* and placed each photo for that date within.

I would like a script to do the following (Windows based computer, so DOS, powershell, or VBscript would work):

Step through each folder, take the date from the folder and apply the following commands:

```
exiftool -datetimeoriginal="19yy:mm:dd 12:00:00" directory\*.jpg
exiftool "-datetimeoriginal+<0:0:${filesequence;$_*=3}" directory\*.jpg
move *.jpg e:\Fixed\
```

Any suggestions?  I haven't scripted in years and am definitely rusty.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by exiftool without scripting.  To set the time stamp, you could run
`exiftool -ext jpg "-DateTimeOriginal<19${Directory;m/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/;$_=$3$1$2} 12:00:00" /path/to/mmddyy/`

Then the incrementing and moving of files can be done with
`exiftool -ext jpg -Directory=e:\Fixed\ -overwrite_original "-datetimeoriginal+<0:0:${filesequence;$_*=3}" /path/to/files/`

The first command takes the directory, looks for 6 consecutive numbers which it assumes is the *mmddyy*, reorders them and applies the result to the `DateTimeOriginal`.  Colon separators are not mandatory for this, see [Exiftool FAQ #5](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q5), 3rd paragraph which starts "Having said this…".  This command does require that the *mmddyy* part of the path is on the command line.  You can't CD to the directory and use a dot as the directory name.  If would also required refinement if there was another pattern of 6 consecutive digits somewhere else in the filepath.

The second command increments the time on each image.  Additionally, it will move each edited file to the `e:\Fixed\` directory as it updates.

In both cases, I used the [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) rather than a wildcard, because wildcards won't work in case you have to recurse into subdirectories (see [Common Mistake #2](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M2)).